# Can't send email from codeigniter. Just reloading page

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, sendmail

I can't send email from my codeigniter. it always reload when i press send button. I don't know what wrong with this code. please help me, so i can send the attached email to destination How can i solve this. The code is below :

```
function send_quotation($no, $email_to, $id_ticket, $problem, $action, $nama)
{

    $this->load->model('service_tracking/trans_service_model');

    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';       
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'examplefrom@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password123';
    $config['priority'] = 1;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['starttls'] = TRUE;

     $data = $this->trans_service_model->get_emaildata($id_ticket);

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
    $this->email->from('examplefrom@gmail.com', 'Example corporation');
    $this->email->to('exampleto@gmail.com');
    $data = $this->trans_service_model->get_emaildata($id_ticket);

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
    $this->email->from('examplefrom@gmail.com', 'Example Corporation');
     $this->email->to('exampleto@gmail.com');


    $this->email->subject('['.$no.'] - '.$nama.' - Quotation Repair');


    $message = "
        This is the email contain quotation";


    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->attach('./quotation/'.$no.'.pdf');

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Comment: figure out where your reload happens - this code suggests nothing of that...

Comment: can you post your `form` and `ajax`

Comment: check your logs for error

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
if (!$this->email->send()) {
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
} else {
    echo "Success";
    //redirect();
}
```

Comment: nothing changed mate. still just reload page and no error message